# Почему исчезает форма фильтрации django-filter при выборе значения фильтра, по которому нет результатов?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

У меня есть личный кабинет пользователя, который может смотреть список сделок, которые относятся к его компании. У каждой сделки есть статус. Также настроен фильтр по статусу. Если пользователь фильтрует сделки по статусу и есть сделки с таким статусом, то фильтр работает отлично и выводит эти сделки, но если нет ни одной сделки в таком статусе, то исчезает даже форма фильтрации.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы при отсутствии результатов по указанному фильтру выводилось сообщение об этом и пользователь имел возможность изменить настройки фильтра.

**models.py:**

```
class Lead(models.Model):

STATUS_CHOISES = [
    ('c', 'Created'),
    ('w', 'In work'),
    ('cl', 'Close'),
    ('s', 'Success'),
]

title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='наименование')
agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOISES, default='c')
publication_date = models.DateField()
```

**filters.py:**

```
class LeadFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['status']
```

**views.py:**

```
class LeadsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Lead
    template_name = 'leads.html'
    context_object_name = 'leads'
    filterset_class = LeadFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Lead.objects.all()
        else:
            try:
                self.agent = get_object_or_404(Agent, users=self.request.user)
                return Lead.objects.filter(agent=self.agent)
            except:
                return False
```

Реализация `get_queryset` через `get_object_or_404` сделана из-за того, что к каждой организации (Агенту) может соответствовать несколько пользователей. соответствие пользователя к организации реализовано через:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
```

Соответственно каждому из них необходимо выводить сделки, относящиеся только к их компании.
Если есть рекомендация как сделать это более изящным способом, буду рад.

Но сейчас главный запрос заключается в том, почему если по настроенному поиску нет результатов, то на выводимой странице вообще пропадает форма поиска? Соответственно, чтобы изменить настройки поиска, надо перезайти на страницу вывода сделок.

**leads.html:**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
<form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <tr>
            <th>Наименование</th>
            <th>Статус</th>
            <th>Агент</th>
            <th>Дата публикации</th>
        </tr>

        {% for lead in leads %}
            <tr>
               <td><a href="{% url 'lead_detail' pk=lead.pk %}">{{ lead.title }}</a></td>
               <td>{{ lead.get_status_display }}</td>
               <td>{{ lead.agent }}</td>
               <td>{{ lead.publication_date }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил путем добавления в `class LeadFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)` следующего куска кода:
`status = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(widget=django_filters.widgets.LinkWidget)`

Теперь **filters.py** выглядит так:

```
class LeadFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    status = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(widget=django_filters.widgets.LinkWidget)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['status']
```

Но появилась новая проблема, которую описал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269102)